# Query returning NULL value for columns

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm very new to using sub queries. When running the following query, the column t_num and timestamp is NULL whereas in the respective table those columns have values.

Table trans contains multiple p_num, trans_amt, trans_balance. I just want to get the transaction that happened before 31-JULY-2017 and before.

```
select 
    p.p_number, 
    p.name, 
    t.t_num, 
    t.timestamp 
from payers p
    left join (
        select p_number, t_num, timestamp from trans a
        where a.timestamp <= '31-JUL-2017' and rownum = 1 
        order by a.timestamp desc
    ) t on t.p_number = p.p_number
where p.p_number in(44545558, 44545559, 44545560, 44545561, 44545562)
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

I tried just running this portion of the query and I can see the t_num and timestamp column values.

```
select p_number, t_num, timestamp from trans a
where a.timestamp <= '31-JUL-2017' and rownum = 1 
order by a.timestamp desc
```

Comment: When you just run the inner query, are there any `p_number` from the list you pass to `IN` in the complete query? I'd guess no.

Comment: @stickybit  You guessed it right, I'm not passing any p_number. It just picks random p_number.

Comment: `'31-JUL-2017'` is a string not a timestamp, you should compare data types properly and not rely on implicit conversion and NLS settings; and your `rownum` filtering isn't right as the ordering happens too late. Neither of which is necessarily relevant... but please include the table DDL; particularly, what are the data types of the two `p_number` columns? Your output *suggests* they might strings and that could cause a problem, but that might just be from how you created/generated your image. (And please post text rather than images...)

Comment: @RedVirus: Then there are no rows from the inner query that satisfy the `ON` clause of the left join. And that's why the columns stay null.

Comment: which datatype is the column  timestamp ???

Comment: @scaisEdge it's DATE

Comment: I don't think that inline view is going to do what you expect - it will filter the results to a single row and then apply the order by. You need to order the results first in a subquery and then filter by the rownum in the outer query, before outer joining that query to the payers table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query first orders data in subquery and takes first which has not proper `p_number`. It's better and safer to use `row_number` in such queries:

```
select p.p_number, p.name, t.t_num, t.timestamp
  from payers p
  left join (select p_number, t_num, timestamp,
                    row_number() over (partition by p_number order by timestamp desc) rn 
               from trans t 
               where t.timestamp <= date '2017-07-31') t
         on p.p_number = t.p_number and rn = 1
  where p.p_number between 44545558 and 44545562
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d719634f7908629cc0dcb27f05b2952)</sup>**

Comment: Thank you. This works. This is my first time using partition. Cheers!